# Failure of large run to save as object

Tags: r, object, mcmc

Hello and apologizes if I am missing information as this is my first post.

I am working on a large data set with MCMCglmm, which involves large runs going into 4000000 and can take up to 12 hours. Within the last week R will complete a run but fail to save the object into the environment past 4000000 iteration, so any results are lost. So far I have tried...

1. Going through all data input
2. Using a separate computer and R studio
3. Created a new project and script
4. Run with a small amount of iterations to ensure it will save then increase it the proper amount. Any advice or experience would be tremendously appreciated.

Error: failure to save to the environment

[image: Error: failure to save to the environment]

Comment: Option 4 still fails? So, you cannot save this specific object at all or when you reach 400k again?

Comment: Your code on `MCMCglmm()` is incomplete. If it is complete, it will create an object `H5`. Make sure that `MCMCglmm()` works properly.

Comment: Hi and apologize, the code is complete (it's just cut off from the poorly done screenshot). But it does run and save when I have the iterations down but fails once it is increased to 4 mill.